# How can I recover files from an Ubuntu Server boot drive?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, minecraft

My old laptop with Ubuntu Server 20.04 on it died recently. I used it as a local Minecraft server for the kids. I would like to back up the Minecraft world from the harddrive.

This is what I tried:

1. I plugged the harddrive into another laptop and fired it up. It gave me the message that the drive was not a bootable one.
2. I connected the drive through USB on an Ubuntu machine and tried to extract .img files after copying them on the local drive. Which is, to be honest, a shot in the dark because I don’t what I’m doing. I managed to get the root file structure but I couldn’t find the Minecraft files.
3. I’ve been looking for similar topics but I didn’t find a solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bootable HDD on a PC should be bootable on another… but if one is BIOS based and the other is EFI based, I can imagine some issues.

The idea to plug the HDD on a working PC (working with its internal drive or a Live distribution on USB stick / CDROM) is a good one, but you don’t have to get the image disk (is it the sense of « extracting .img » ?), but just to mount it, then copy the files from the mounted image elsewhere.

You should be more precise about what you have succeed to do and what fails and how. (Is mounting the HDD done ? Have you seen your files ? What is the error message when trying to copy your files, with what command ?)

Comment: I solved it. I am a bit embarassed but I mounted only one partition. There was a second one. Your question if the mounting was done made me think again.